# Showing the original details while review audit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

I have passed a [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1575477) for first posts today.

It is very simple to pass this type of audit since I can see the details of that post in the right side as below

> [image]

The info of `23 days ago` clearly shows me that it's an audit, no need of taking a glance to the post, just see the time.

One can easily review by seeing the posting time -

> if it is 17 minutes ago or 18 mins ago just upvote or downvote (it is
>   better to upvote, DV for answer reduce reps) or click no action needed,
>   if it is `13 days ago` or `23 days ago` means just downvote or flag

Counting the time taken for review alone not give better reviews, it needs some tricks like the audits should show fake details like `asked 10 minutes ago for a closed question of 23 days ago` means, it would be much better.

Audits should also include some Great [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/756941) and [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) to check whether it gets downvote or flagged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1575477 - audit reference.

Comment: Completely agree with you! They could also add "exact duplicates" as audit. Some obvious ones. I think audits are a great thing but could get a bit more difficult just to make the reviewer more aware of the task they are doing